# Get string between two characters in php

Tags: php, regex, preg-match, preg-match-all, pcre

I have a string in php say

```
$string = 'All I want to say is that <#they dont really care#> about us.
    I am wasted away <#I made a million mistake#>, am I too late. 
    Theres a storm in my head and a race on my bed, <#when you are not near#>' ;


$expected_output = array(
    'they dont really care',
    'I made a million mistake',
    'when you are not near'
);
```

How can I acheive this using PHP regex ?
Thanks for reading :)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

A more compact version:

```
$regex = '~<#\K.*?(?=#>)~';
preg_match_all($regex, $string, $matches);
print_r($matches[0]);
```

See the matches in [the regex demo](http://regex101.com/r/nJ8cJ8/38).

**Matches**

```
they dont really care
I made a million mistake
when you are not near
```

**Explanation**

- The `^` anchor asserts that we are at the beginning of the string
- `<#` matches the left delimiter
- The `\K` tells the engine to drop what was matched so far from the final match it returns
- `.*?` lazily matches chars up to the point where...
- The lookahead `(?=#>)` can assert that what follows is `#>`
- The `$` anchor asserts that we are at the end of the string

**Reference**

- [Lookahead and Lookbehind Zero-Length Assertions](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html)
- [Mastering Lookahead and Lookbehind](http://www.rexegg.com/regex-lookarounds.html)

Answer (score 1):

This code will do what you want

```
<?php

$string = 'All I want to say is that <#they dont really care#> about us.
    I am wasted away <#I made a million mistake#>, am I too late. 
    Theres a storm in my head and a race on my bed, <#when you are not near#>' ;


preg_match_all('/<#(.*)#>/isU', $string, $matches);

var_dump($matches[1]);
```

Answer (score 0):

Through lookahead and lookbehind,

```
(?<=<#).*?(?=#>)
```

Finally call `preg_match_all` function to print the matched strings.

Your **PHP code** would be,

```
<?php
$data = 'All I want to say is that <#they dont really care#> about us.
    I am wasted away <#I made a million mistake#>, am I too late. 
    Theres a storm in my head and a race on my bed, <#when you are not near#>' ;
$regex =  '~(?<=<#).*?(?=#>)~';
preg_match_all($regex, $data, $matches);
var_dump($matches);
?>
```

**Output:**

```
array(1) {
  [0]=>
  array(3) {
    [0]=>
    string(21) "they dont really care"
    [1]=>
    string(24) "I made a million mistake"
    [2]=>
    string(21) "when you are not near"
  }
}
```